# GoogleCharts 3D effects are missing in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, google-visualization

In my application, i have Google Charts(Pie and Column)..
While testing my app in IE 9 ,charts are missing 3D effects...

**Used:**
google.load('visualization', '1.1', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });   when i use "corechart" only im able to see both(Pie,coloumn)charts in IE9.

**If i use** 
google.load('visualization', '1.1', { 'packages': ['piechart'] });
google.load('visualization', '1.1', { 'packages': ['columnchart'] }); in my app,im not able to see charts in IE9.0...so used "corechart"..with this im getting charts in IE9 bt 3D effects missing..pls help

Answer (score 1):

its not due to IE, api is not supporting 3d functionality with corechars. see google release-notes

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes 
Unsupported Options:
3D - Pie charts do not support a 3D version at the moment.